# django rest framework comment system

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a rest api with django and having hard times with comment system. The API shows my comments correctly but it shows replies to comments twice. One at comments field of post, other at replies field of comments. Like both in depth 1 and 2. So to cut short, there is my code:

--**serializers.py**

```
class CommentChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Comment.objects.all(),source='parent.id')
    author = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author', 'content', 'id','parent_id')

    def get_author(self, obj):
        return obj.author.username

    def create(self, validated_data):
        subject = parent.objects.create(parent=validated_data['parent']['id'], content=validated_data['content'])

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reply_count = SerializerMethodField()
    author = SerializerMethodField()
    replies = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id','content', 'parent', 'author', 'reply_count', 'replies')
        # depth = 1

    def get_reply_count(self, obj):
        if obj.is_parent:
            return obj.children().count()
        return 0

    def get_author(self, obj):
        return obj.author.username

    def get_replies(self, obj):
        if obj.is_parent:
            return CommentChildSerializer(obj.children(), many=True).data
        return None

class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = post_detail_url
    author = SerializerMethodField()
    image = SerializerMethodField()
    comments = CommentSerializer(required=False, many=True)
    # comments = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'image', 'author', 'star_rate', 'url', 'slug', 'comments')

    def get_author(self, obj):
         return obj.author.username

    def get_image(self, obj):
        try:
            image = obj.image.url
        except:
            image = None
        return image
```

--**comment model**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='replies')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment by {self.author.username} on {self.post}'

    def children(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(parent=self)

    @property
    def is_parent(self):
        if self.parent is not None:
            return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your view look like? If you want only comments with no parent to display as top-level comments, then you'll need to make sure that the queryset populating your serializer filters appropriately, e.g. `Comment.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)`

Comment: view looks like that:                                                                                                         ```class CommentAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
        queryset = Comment.objects.all()
        serializer_class = CommentSerializer```

Comment: That solution didn't work. I think the serializer filters are the problem. I need something like if comment has parent_id then it shouldn't be shown at main comment flow.

Comment: right, your queryset gets all comments, even those that are only supposed to be shown as replies; then all comments with replies *separately* muster a list of their replies for display as replies. your line `queryset = Comment.objects.all()` must be edited to exclude comments which have a parent, so that they are only populated via the `get_replies()` method on your serializer. my suggested replacement above may not be perfect but that's the direction you should explore to find a solution.